# MultiValueDictKeyError at /upload/

Tags: django, file-upload

i need some help with Django, i keep encounter the MultiValueDictKeyError when i click the download button. And it shows MultiValueDictKeyError at /upload/
'my_file' but not sure how to solve it after several attempts. Below are my codes for models, view, and the template page. For your advice please.

files_ul_dl.html

```
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
                <input type="file" name="my_file">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit">Upload</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <hr>

        <h4>File Type Count</h4>
        <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
                {% for file_type in file_types %}
                    <th scope="col">{{ file_type }}</th>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
                {% for file_type_count in file_type_counts %}
                    <td>{{ file_type_count }}</td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>

        <br/>

        <h4>Files</h4>
        <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">#</th>
              <th scope="col">file name</th>
              <th scope="col">size</th>
              <th scope="col">file type</th>
              <th scope="col">upload date</th>
              <th scope="col"></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {% for file in files %}
                {% url 'files_upload:download_file' as download_file_url%}

                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">{{ forloop.counter }}</th>
                  <td>{{ file.upload.name }}</td>
                  <td>{{ file.size }}</td>
                  <td>{{ file.file_type }}</td>
                  <td>{{ file.upload_datetime }}</td>
                  <td>
                    <form action="{{ download_file_url }}" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form }}
                    <input type="hidden" name="path" value="{{ file.upload.name }}">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary label-success" value="Download" />
                    </form>
                  </td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
          </tbody>
        </table><hr>
```

views.py

```
def files_upload(request):
    context = {}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        uploaded_file = request.FILES['my_file']
        if uploaded_file.content_type not in file_content_types:
            print("INVALID CONTENT TYPE")

        else:
            new_file = File(upload=uploaded_file, file_type=uploaded_file.content_type)
            new_file.save()
            print(uploaded_file.content_type)

    qs = File.objects.all().order_by('-upload_datetime')
    context['files'] = qs

    context["file_types"] = file_content_types
    file_type_counts = []
    for file_type in file_content_types:
        count = File.objects.filter(file_type=file_type).count()
        file_type_counts.append(count)

    context["file_type_counts"] = file_type_counts

    return render(request, "files_ul_dl.html", context)


def download_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        path = request.POST.get('path')
        print(path)
        file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, path)
        if os.path.exists(file_path):
            with open(file_path, 'rb') as fh:
                response = HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type="application/force-download")
                response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=' + os.path.basename(file_path)
                return response
    raise Http404
```

Comment: Hi, i have made edits to show my html file and i have included enctype="multipart/form-data" however the uploading of file works but not the download button, once i click the button it shows the MultiValueDictKeyError

Comment: Apologies, i just redited it. forgot to copy the form part.

Comment: You say you get the error when you click the download button, but `download_view` doesn't access `request.FILES`. It sounds like the form action in the rendered template is incorrect, or you have an issue in your URL patterns.

Comment: Yup, only when i clicked the download button that error shows and it pointed to the statement "uploaded_file = request.FILES['my_file'] " which is in the in the upload section of views.py. I have been trying for hours to try to solve but to no avail. My URL as follows
    url(r'^upload/', views.files_upload, name="files_upload"),
    url(r'^download/', views.download_view, name="download_file"),

Comment: Your regexes should contain dollar signs, e.g. `r'^upload/$'`, otherwise it will match `upload/foo/` as well as `upload/`. However those two patterns shouldn't clash. What does `<form action="{{ download_file_url }}" method="post">` appear as in the rendered template? It sounds like `{% url 'files_upload:download_file' as download_file_url%}` might be failing silently. Also, why do you have `{{ form }}` when you don't use `form` anywhere in your views?

Comment: Oh ya you're right i have removed the {{ form }} actually i followed a project on github the codes (https://github.com/taylerallen6/Django_file_upload_download). I am trying to upload the files into the local static folder, then from there the download button will be able to download back the file which was uploaded in the static folder. It's kinda weird as when i download the whole project file via github it works, but when i try to incorporate into my project its not working for the download button.

Comment: The `{{ form }}` wasn't the main issue, it's the part about the form action and `{% url %}` tag that you really need to investigate.

Comment: Really have no idea what's going on, when i run it with the original project source it seems to be working..

Comment: You need to debug your project where it's not working.  As I asked before, what does `<form action="{{ download_file_url }}" method="post">` appear as in the rendered template. If `{% url 'files_upload:download_file' as download_file_url%}` isn't working in your project, it could be because you aren't using `app_name=files_upload`, so the namespace in the `{% url %}` tag is incorrect.

Comment: I’m very new to programming, so I don’t really know how to test and debug my codes... it’s weird that the sample is working but this is not :(

Comment: I understand that you're new, but repeatedly saying that the original is working is not going to help. You've just got to figure out what the difference is between the sample and your project. I've said three times to check what `<form action="{{ download_file_url }}" method="post">` appears as in the rendered template. If you don't understand what I'm asking, then please say so, instead of ignoring it.

Comment: Actually I don’t know how to check / debug >< I was looking at it but didn’t think there’s something wrong with it

Comment: In your browser, right click, and use the "View Page Source" option. Then look for the download form, and post the rendered code here.

Comment: <form action="" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="oLrsFCdvdHt1wv6gSbGfPfMDS1JGoMGEQYdQflRuG2VXWgKjU5P9LmykgCXcVJ3d">
       <input type="hidden" name="path" value="files/2012_November_Paper_1.pdf">
       <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary label-success" value="Download" />
      </form>

Comment: my files folder is under media_root, does it means that the url is incorrect?

Comment: `<form action="" method="post">` is the problem. It means that you are posting the form to the current page `/upload/` instead of the download page. That means that `{% url 'files_upload:download_file' as download_file_url %}` isn't working. First check that the download URL pattern has `name='download_file'`, then check that the `urls.py` has `app_name = 'files_upload'` (to match the `files_upload:` namespace in the `{% url %}` tag).

Comment: The problem with `{% url 'files_upload:download_file' as download_file_url %}` is that it fails silently, so you end up with the incorrect `action=""`. If you temporarily change it to `{% url 'files_upload:download_file' %}`, then you'll get an error message that will help solve the problem.

Comment: when i remove and amend and remove 'as download_file_url, it shows the error 'files_upload' is not a registered namespace. in my urls.py

Comment: i think is because i do not have this app_name = 'files_upload'

Comment: OMG, thank you for your guides! i have solved it by changing it to {% url download_file as download_file_url %} and form action="{{download_file_url}}"